# Databound ErrorProvider not blinking

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation, errorprovider

I have an error provider on my form that has its datasource bound to a collection of Errors in my record class:

[image: error provider debug hover over]

The validation is working as I expect, however the red blinking icon does not appear next to my form controls. My record implements IDataErrorInfo:

```
    Public ReadOnly Property [Error] As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Error
        Get
            If _Errors.Count > 0 Then
                Return String.Format("The record cannot be saved because there are {0} errors", _Errors.Count)
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets an error message for the property with the given name
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Default Public ReadOnly Property PropertyError(fieldName As String) As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Item
        Get
            If _Errors.ContainsKey(fieldName) Then
                Return _Errors(fieldName).ToString
            Else
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
```

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated as I'm completely stuck.

Comment: I think that my problem is due to a mismatch between my record property names, and the control names on the form. Will update with an answer when I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by my adding the errors to the collection using the control names e.g. StaticBalancesOOSReasonValue" and then trying to retrieve them from the IDataErrorInfo.PropertyError method using the property names e.g. "StaticBalancesOOSReason". Now that's fixed the icons display.